# How to create a complex JSON string using C#?

Tags: c#, json

I need to create json string which looks like this:

```
{
  "key0": [{ "key00": "value00" }, { "key00": "value01" }, ...], 
  "key1": [{ "key11": "value10" }, { "key11": "value11" }, ...],
  ......
}
```

For generation of this string I use string operations and regular expressions.
But perhaps there is a way to make it easier? For example, using Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Create the object structure in C# and serialize it to JSON?

Comment: You use regular expressions to generate a string? First of all: how? Secondly: why? Thirdly: yes, use Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json, or whatever Json lib out there.

Comment: "Yes! there is". Try it, I bet you will like it.

Comment: I'd recommend you start with System.Text.Json rather than Newtonsoft.Json. If your "keys" are dynamic (literally "key0", "key1", etc.) you can use a Dictionary with strings as the keys. If they're known at compile-time, I'd declare a class to represent the model and serialize to JSON.

Comment: Check [Microsoft Docs: How to write .NET objects as JSON (serialize)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to)

Comment: use online converter if you want to cheat https://json2csharp.com/